# xml checkbox toggle issue

Tags: android, xml, apk

I have multiple option checkboxes (and I plan on adding more) that I would like to have a restriction to one selected at a time. How would I do that?

Here's my xml: (ignore the "Receipt Modes" string, that's just a title)

```
    <kik.android.widget.preferences.KikEmptyPreference android:enabled="false" android:title="Receipt Modes:"/>
    <kik.android.widget.preferences.ReadingPref android:enabled="true" android:title="Delivered Mode" android:key="kik.reading.toggle" android:summary="Your messages will be displayed as 'D' (delivered)" />
    <kik.android.widget.preferences.OfflinePref android:enabled="true" android:title="Offline Mode" android:key="kik.reading.toggle" android:summary="Your messages will be displayed as 'S' (Sent)" />
```

Comment: You should use radio buttons in a radio group then to achieve that. I don't know that kind of checkboxes you use.

Comment: @HusseinElFeky Isn't that HTML? I'm working on modifying an apk.

Comment: if you're talking preferences, you could use a `ListPreference`

Comment: I really don't know what you are using. If you can give more details about these kinds of checkboxes, I'll try to help you.

Comment: @karaokyo A ListPreference would do exactly what I want it to do, but how can I get it to work like the checkbox strings above? (toggle a .smali pref file with the android:key)

Comment: you have two elements that has  enable =true, is that by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a standard `ListPreference` implementation by creating a settings activity:

`New > Activity > Settings Activity`

---

```
<ListPreference
        android:key="kik.reading.toggle"
        android:title="Receipt Modes"
        android:defaultValue="D"
        android:entries="@array/toggle_list_titles"
        android:entryValues="@array/toggle_list_values"/>
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="toggle_list_titles">
    <item>Delivered Mode</item>
    <item>Offline Mode</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="toggle_list_values">
    <item>D</item>
    <item>S</item>
</string-array>
```